# PHP PDO initialization fails due to "double port" - Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I get this error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Failed to parse address "localhost:3306:3306" in [myPath]/xxDb.php:32

Notice the "double" port in the address: ***localhost:3306:3306***

`xxDb.php line` 32 looks like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PW, array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8" ));
```

dumping DB_HOST results in `localhost:3306`.

I can not see where the second port part `3306` comes from which obviously exists during the connection initialization.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: downvoting a question without a comment... great. SO rules...

Comment: Downvoting does not require leaving a comment, it is only suggested (it wasn't me either). Is `DB_HOST` set manually? If yes, then try removing the port from it, changing it to just `localhost`

Comment: DB_HOST is set by a CMS system and varies according to the settings of the user (this code belongs to a part of a plugin). Can you think of any reason why this port is duplicated? There is no separate setting of the port anywhere and it seems that the PDO constructor just doubles it (which I don't really believe..). I am lost.

Comment: What CMS/Platform is this? Also what server environment is this running on?

Comment: @PhilS CMS: XT Commerce (4.2 and higher). I can't really tell you about the server environment - it's not under my control. I know it's at least PHP 5.4 though...

Comment: @PhilS However - I can figure out some specifics. Can you tell me which information would help?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I have zero experience with that platform, sorry I can't offer anything that would assist.

Comment: I understand `DB_HOST` is set by a CMS, but maybe the port needs to be specified as its own value. Like `host=x;port=x;`. See [PDO_MYSQL DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). I believe 3306 is the default port, so maybe you can omit it altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

showdev's comment is correct that the PDO DSN does not allow host:port syntax.

If your CMS is defining DB_HOST outside of your control, you can't use that constant directly. But you can pull information out of it.

```
$host_port = preg_replace('/:(\d+)/', ';port=${1}', DB_HOST);
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host_port};dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=utf8", 
    DB_USER, DB_PW, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Defining "host" and "port" separately fixes it.

Comment: Does anyone know since when the PDO DNS doesn't accept host:port syntax? This issue has just arisen with us and this solution worked.

Comment: @ElliotReed, since at least 2005, according to https://github.com/php/php-src/blame/master/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c look at the code in lines 798-802 and "blame" commit history in the left column shows how old those lines of code are.