# PHP PDO MySQL Tunnel Connection Double Port

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, port, tunnel

Before i've installed my app and works fine but when i make new installation on other device with same code and config,
i got error when trying to connect tunneling mysql with pdo extensions on **yii 1**.

The error message like this:

> CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Failed to parse address "localhost:3307:3306"

I just want to connect with port `3307` but `:3306` auto included

I've tried some method but keep not working

My main config:

```
'db' => array(
    'class' => 'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString' => !empty($ini['db']['conn_str'])
        ? $ini['db']['conn_str'] : 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',
    'username' => !empty($ini['db']['user'])
        ? $ini['db']['user'] : 'root',
    'password' => isset($ini['db']['password'])
        ? $ini['db']['password'] : 'xxx',
    'tablePrefix' => !empty($ini['db']['prefix'])
        ? $ini['db']['prefix'] : 'dcl_',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'schemaCachingDuration' => 86400,
    'enableParamLogging' => TRUE,
    'enableProfiling' => TRUE,
),

'dbmm' => array(
    'class' => 'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString' => !empty($ini['dbmm']['conn_str'])
        ? $ini['dbmm']['conn_str'] : 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',
    'username' => !empty($ini['dbmm']['user'])
        ? $ini['dbmm']['user'] : 'root',
    'password' => isset($ini['dbmm']['password'])
        ? $ini['dbmm']['password'] : 'xxx',
    'tablePrefix' => !empty($ini['dbmm']['prefix'])
        ? $ini['dbmm']['prefix'] : 'mm_',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'schemaCachingDuration' => 86400,
    'enableParamLogging' => TRUE,
    'enableProfiling' => TRUE,
    'attributes' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true
    ),
),

'dbantrian' => array(
    'class' => 'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString' => !empty($ini['dbantrian']['conn_str'])
        ? $ini['dbantrian']['conn_str'] : 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx',
    'username' => !empty($ini['dbantrian']['user'])
        ? $ini['dbantrian']['user'] : 'root',
    'password' => isset($ini['dbantrian']['password'])
        ? $ini['dbantrian']['password'] : 'xxx',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'schemaCachingDuration' => 86400,
    'enableParamLogging' => TRUE,
    'enableProfiling' => TRUE,
),
```

My .ini file:

```
[db]
conn_str = "mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=xxx"
user = "root"
password = "xxx"
prefix = "dcl_"

[dbmm]
conn_str = "mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=xxx"
user = "root"
password = "xxx"
prefix = "mm_"

[dbantrian]
conn_str = "mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=xxx"
user = "root"
password = "xxx"
```

The tools what i use:

- Ubuntu 16
- Ajenti V
- Nginx
- PHP 5.6
- PDO and PDO Mysql
- MariaDB 5.7

I can't use the solution from [PHP PDO initialization fails due to "double port" - Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516741/php-pdo-initialization-fails-due-to-double-port-uncaught-pdoexception-sqlst) because i disallowed to update core files of yii

I don't know what i miss

Thanks before and sorry for my english

Update:
My app on old device has error (like on my new app) after `sudo apt upgrade`

```
Setting up php5.6-common (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-curl (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-sqlite3 (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-mbstring (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-xml (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-gd (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-readline (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-mcrypt (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-json (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-mysql (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-opcache (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-cli (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php5.6-fpm (5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 5.6 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 5.6 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php5.6-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Setting up php-msgpack (2.0.2+0.5.7-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+2) ...
Setting up php-mysql (1:7.1+52+deb.sury.org~xenial+1) ...
Setting up php-pgsql (1:7.1+52+deb.sury.org~xenial+1) ...
```

Comment: What does your PDO connection code look like? Edit your question to add that and it should be more obvious what's wrong.

Comment: Edited. I'm using Yii1, so i just add connection config

Comment: solved. change `host=localhost:3307` to `host=127.0.0.1;port=3307`

Comment: So it was two problems, one being `localhost` and the other the format of the `port=` part.

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

The configuration string should look like:

```
mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;...
```

The `port` part must be separated from the `host`.

Comment: i've tried thats code but not work. when i use above method, yii like ignored port value

Comment: It's right out of the [PDO manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), as per the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html), so I don't know what to say.